# Selecting text while the document is being changed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a real time logging page where I fetch data with ajax and add it to the document.

I want to be able to select and copy parts of the text in this log but if I'm doing the selecting at the same time that a new line is added to the log, it messes it up and I have to start over.

Here's an example, try to select the second "hey" that appears:

```js
 var div = document.createElement("div");
 document.body.appendChild(div);
 var add = function() {
  div.innerHTML += "<div>hey</div>";
  if (div.children.length < 100) setTimeout(add, 300);
 }
 add();
```

Is there any way to fix that without interrupting the incoming log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selection is "destroyed" because you overwrite the whole `<div>` content on each run. So it's a "new *hey*" on second row every 300 ms.

Using `appendChild` instead should work:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(div);
var add = function () {
  var node = document.createElement('div');
  node.innerText = 'hey';
  div.appendChild(node);
  if (div.children.length < 10) setTimeout(add, 300);
};
add();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `appendChild` new `div`s to the body rather than doing `innerHTML +=`. That's much more efficient anyway. And anything you're selecting won't involve divs that the browser is updating.

```
function add() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "log string";  // SECURITY WARNING: don't let user strings in here
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    // do something to reschedule add
}
add();
```